# What is the difference between event driven programming and the propagation of constraints?

Tags: constraint-programming

They both seem to be very similar from what I've read online. Wouldn't a propagation of constraints be the same as event driven programming? The reason I say this is because when the constraint is satisfied, would that be considered an event?

Comment: The fact that languages like JavaScript are used for event-driven programming and languages like Prolog are used for constraint programming suggests that the problem domains are fairly distinct (those languages are radically different from each other). Having said that, obviously everything is connected if you dig deep enough. For example, constraint programming could possibly be used to model what happens in event-driven programming. I am a little more skeptical that event-driven programming provides a useful perspective on constraint programming.